# Use fancybox previous / next as iframe's history buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I'm using jquery Fancybox to display some pages within an iFrame. Thoses pages got links to go to other pages, so I would like to make the Fancybox previous and next buttons to go to the previous and next page in the iFrame history. Is it possible to change this behavior ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: accessing the `history.length` of a document contained inside an iframe from the parent page is bit of a challenge. First, both pages must be within the same domain. Second you have to validate the returned value of `history.length`, which can be different depending on the browser. Third, you have to `unbind` the current events of the fancybox navigation arrows and bind them again depending on the returned value of `history.length` on-the-fly. I would rather go for adding the buttons inside the iframed page instead otherwise you may have to sharp your javascript skills or have a good budget ;)

Comment: You definitely convinced me ;-) Thanks a lot !